# 'Simple' PHP script shows error in line 10, what have I done wrong?

Tags: email, php

My freshly updated website has a contact form with php mail script which I based on the form script [here](http://myphpform.com/final-form.php).

The script is saved on my webserver, but when data is submitted, no mails are sent as there is a fault in line 10.

I honestly don't understand enough to pinpoint my error - can someone help a newbie out?

I found a temporary replacement by using Bravenet, but I'd like to use my unbranded version, if simple php scripts are as simple as they seem…

My script (kontakt.php) looks like this:

```
 <?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "edw@rdturner.co.uk";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Ihr Name");
$email  = check_input($_POST['email'], "Ihre E-Mail-Adresse");
$kontaktnummer    = check_input($_POST['kontaktnummer']);
$thema   = check_input($_POST['them']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message']), "Worum geht's?");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail-Adresse ungültig");
}



/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hallo!

Ihr Form ist unterwegs…:

Name: $name
E-Mail-Adresse: $email
Kontaktnummer: $kontaktnummer
Frage zum Thema? $thema

Nachricht: $message


Comments:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: danke.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Hier stimmt was nicht - bitte prüfen!</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

and my submission form like this:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://pub14.bravenet.com/emailfwd/senddata.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="usernum" value="1126560145">
<input type="hidden" name="cpv" value="2">
          <ol><li>
            <label for="name">Name (Erförderlich)</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" class="text" />
          </li><li>
            <label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse (Erförderlich)</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="text" />
          </li><li>
<label for="kontaktnummer">Kontaktnummer (Erförderlich)</label>
            <input id="kontaktnummer" name="kontaktnummer" class="text" />
          </li><li>
            <label for="thema">Fragen zum Thema (Erförderlich)</label></br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="thema" value="unterricht" /> Unterricht</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="thema" value="übersetzungen" /> Übersetzungen</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="thema" value="dolmetschen" /> Dolmetschen</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="thema" value="faß" /> Englsich vom Faß</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="thema" value="anders" /> Andere
          </li><li>
            <label for="message">Worum geht's? (Erförderlich)</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
          </li><li>
            <input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/submit.gif" class="send" />
            <div class="clr"></div>
          </li></ol>
          </form>
```

Naturally I'll need to tweak the html to reflect the newly working script… but how?

Thanks in advance

Edd Turner

Comment: $message = check_input($_POST['message']), "Worum geht's?");      -->$message = check_input($_POST['message']);   or   $message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Worum geht's?");

Comment: I see you noted the line number but chose to ignore the error message. That's not a good debugging technique. Error messages have a purpose: to help diagnose issues. Don't guess!

Comment: That was it? Thank you! I'll try and get back to you ASAP

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = check_input($_POST['message']), "Worum geht's?");
```

to

```
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Worum geht's?");
```

There is a ) in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = check_input($_POST['message']), "Worum geht's?");
```

Excessive `)`, try `$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Worum geht's?");'`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the extra ')'. The error is in this line.

Change

```
$message = check_input($_POST['message']), "Worum geht's?");
```

to

```
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Worum geht's?");
```